# How to mark a commit with a version that can be used in composer.json

Tags: git, composer-php, versioning

In my git repository, how can i set its versions? How can I mark a commit in a way it can be used like "vendor/package": "@dev"?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: Libraries > [Specifying the version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version)